# Entity Framework and arrays of complex data

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to update an old linq to sql program, which has a table ("tables") with an array of listed items on it. Now, this list is heavily modified and sorted by the GUI, so there is really no way to keep it as a master/slave table relationship. Also, it has to keep the order it was last generated.

Is there a preferred way to do this? I don't want to keep track of a *position* column, I just want a List items to be stored in the way it is right now.

Currently, I use json to store it in one column (using property accessors), but for various reasons I want to access the data from pure SQL from time to time, reading and not modifying in that case.

Is there a best way to do this, or do I need to override object properties and savechanges() much as I did back in the L2SQL phase?

The subtable has about 20 fields - that would make the "complex" type. And it's even worse, is has a hierarchical structure, think of a tree more than a list, but limited to 2 levels.

It's kind of hard to show code for this - it's a million-lines project - but the part I want to get rid of is like this:

```
    public static T FromByte<T>(this T source, Byte[] text) {
  Type[] knownTypes = new Type[] { typeof(IrsTable), typeof(IrsSubtableItem), typeof(IrsSubtablePlayer) };

  DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T), knownTypes, int.MaxValue, false, true, null);
  try {
    using (MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Compressor.Decompress(text))) {
      using (XmlDictionaryReader xr = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(ms, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max)) {
        T t = (T)dcs.ReadObject(xr);
        var apa = from prop in typeof(T).GetProperties()
                  where prop.Name == "ID"
                  select prop;
        if (apa.Any())
          apa.First().SetValue(t, 0, null);
        return t;
      }
    }
  } catch {
    throw;
  }
}
```

Now, I don't quite get the editor here - no tags shown, no idea if this looks right. But that's the extract part today. Basically the subtable is compressed into one column and the ID is duplicated to the extracted class ..

It's used from code, as in:

```
          IrsTable it = new IrsTable().FromByte(itbl.Tbl.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some code from the project, that way someone or myself can try and help you better.

Comment: I updated with the "extract" code. Not sure how that helps, this is what I want to get away from :)